# Conda works no more: "ImportError: cannot import name get_server_api"

Tags: ubuntu, pip, anaconda

After upgrading Ubuntu to the newest LTS (and perhaps doing some other shenanigans, I don't recall when exactly this was working the last time), I cannot search for packages using anaconda:

```
$ anaconda search -t conda bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/bin/anaconda", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/scripts/cli.py", line 94, in main
    description=__doc__, version=version)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/scripts/cli.py", line 60, in binstar_main
    add_subparser_modules(parser, sub_command_module)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clyent/__init__.py", line 115, in add_subparser_modules
    for command_module in get_sub_commands(module):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clyent/__init__.py", line 105, in get_sub_commands
    this_module = __import__(module.__package__ or module.__name__, fromlist=names)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/download.py", line 13, in <module>
    from binstar_client.utils import get_server_api
ImportError: cannot import name get_server_api
```

I already re-installed requests. What else can be behind this?

Comment: What is the output of `conda list` and `conda info`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on Mac OS. Try to run

```
conda update anaconda-client
```

This updated from v1.1 to v1.5.5. The next run of jupyter notebook was error free.